# Can I create salesforce reports showing user activity?

Tags: audit-fields, field-audit-trail

I need to create reports on a specific user, basically what they've done in recent days in terms of edits/deletes of records on some of the standard SF data objects.

I thought that this would be possible by making reports against the 'Individual' or 'Individual History' report types, but it doesn't seem to return any records.

From what I see in other posts this data is all available via API but I really need a quick solution that works via the standard SF interface.  Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1 Event Log Monitoring

One way to do this is to license [Salesforce Event Monitoring](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro) that will write all URI interactions done by a given user to Event Log files.

Typically orgs will then have some enterprise-grade logger consume these events for use in analytics applications (e.g. Sumo Logic)

There is no way in the standard SFDC UX to get this information - you need the Event Monitoring feature

### Option 2 - History records

This will get you creates and edits, not deletes. For example, the Account History object shows changes to any field that you track on the Account.

Limitation - it only works for tracked fields so if a user edits an untracked field, there is no history record to query.

### Option 2a - deletes

You'll need a custom object to track these and either flows or triggers to write entries to this custom object on delete events. Fields would be:

- `Deleted_RecordId__c`
- `Deleted_Record_Name__c`
- `CreatedById` (OOTB - running user)